# Magento 1.9.2.4 set customer last login

Tags: magento

I am importing customer data and want to set the datetime of last login (available from imported data). This should then display in the admin under Customers info where it gives the "Last Logged in" datetime in following screen:

[image: Customer admin screen]

When I implement the following code:

```
$customerLog = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->load($customer->getId());
$customerLog->setData('customer_id',$customer->getId())
            ->setLoginAt('Y-m-d h:i:s') // actual datetime used here
            ->save();
```

... I get the expected login_at entries in the log_customer table,

[image: screenshot of phpMyAdmin customer_log table]

...but in the Magento backend I always see "Last Logged in: Never (Offline)" when I view the customer. I have enabled logs in Configuration->System->Log but this makes not difference. Why does the Last Logged in not get updated in the customer screen?

Answer (score 0):

where did you put this message? some of the block are cached (like header links, menu, footer)

please try to put this in some other place as test.

also, please provide the code you used to print the last logged message.

Comment: The "Last Logged in" message is standard Magento feature and is displayed on the Customer screen when you Edit a customer.